# AJAX Internal 500 Error in Wordpress Children-Theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I got this Ajax code on Js/Jq block (/buscador/menuLateral/menu-libros.php):

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>' +
    '/buscador/buscador-functions.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    sendCheckedVal: 'yes',
    tipo: 'editorial',
    valor: valor_recogido,
    archivo: this_file_id.toString()
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Checked value !');
  }
});
```

Values on this file exists and got some value, I tried seeing it with a GET on a Stringify.

And this, must be getted in a file like this (*/buscador/buscador-functions.php)* :

```
<?php
    if (ISSET($_POST['sendCheckedVal'])){
       echo 'hi, u reached here' ;
    }
?>
```

The values doesn't passes from js code file to next.

I get this error on console:

> POST
>   [WP-URL-HIDDEN-ON-PURPOSE]/themes/ChildrenNewspaper/buscador/buscador-functions.php
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

On right side of the line-error :

> jquery.min.js:2

Someone knows how to repair this on ajax working on a wordpress theme.Thanks

Comment: You appear to be placing JS code (the `alert()` call) in your PHP. This cannot work, and is causing your problem. You need to return a valid response to the AJAX request from your PHP code, then work with that response in the JS. I'd suggest you look at some example AJAX requests between JS and PHP, as well as investigate the difference between client and server side code, as you seem rather confused.

Comment: there is no alert function in php. you need to echo ('hi, u reached here'); instead of alert('hi, u reached here');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is here : `alert('hi, u reached here');`. `alert()` is not `PHP` function it is `javascript` function. So instead of it you can use `echo`or `return`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sendCheckedVal'])){
       echo 'hi, u reached here';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start you off, `alert` is a javascript function.
In php you need to `echo` out values to the page;

If you want to do it with JS you need to print out js.

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('hi, u reached here');</script>";`

Or you can `echo` out the vars to the page.